# Launch Android app from email

Tags: launching

*if app is installed open app if app is not installed then open url in browser. When user see his/her email and click on email which is sent by us. Thanks in advance*

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity android:name=".SampleActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```